# What's different from the two ways with an interface?

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, implements

Write a stand along interface or not like this,

```
spinner.setAdapter(this.mAdapter); 
OnItemSelectedListener spinnerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener(this,this.mAdapter);  
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){ 
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"The planet is "+  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
textViewa.setText("You choose :"+ " " + mAdapter.getItem(arg2));
arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
 }    
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {    
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    textViewa.setText("NONE");
            arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
     }    
});
```

and this one,

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {     ...  
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int pos, long id) {         // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using         // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)     }      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {         // Another interface callback     } }
```

what's different?

Comment: One is directly, another with an implements. which is more standard written? thannks

Comment: this is really a matter of preference IMO, both are perfectly acceptable

Comment: I use the first if there is only one `Spinner` and the second with multiple `Spinner`s then `switch` on the `parent` selected. But yes, just preference, they both do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much @tyczj and codeMagic for your succinct summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's different?

The first option creates an **anonymous inner class** that implements the interface. This is useful when you need multiple `OnItemSelectedListener` implementations that differ significantly.

In the second option, your Activity implements `OnItemSelectedListener`, so (assuming that you pass `this` to each of your Spinners) every Spinner will go to the same `OnItemSelectedListener`  instance.

> which is more standard written?

It depends on your personal preference and your use case. 
If all of your Spinners have similar behavior or simple enough behavior that `onItemSelected()` will be short, then the latter option would work fine.

However, if each of your Spinners is highly unique and share little common code in `onItemSelected()`, then creating a new `OnItemSelectedListener` instance for each Spinner might be a better design decision.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of making Activity implement an Interface is that you will have one object less to allocate and collect. But making anonymous implementation is not a big drawback.
As tyczj said, it's really a matter of preference. If it does something like triggering visibility I would make it anonymous so you don't have to search the overridden method in Activity class.

Comment: thank you for your complement.

Answer (score 1):

They are both equivalent and like tyczj says it is a matter of preference. The reason why sometimes implementing the interface instead of creating an anonymous inner class is preferred is for example if you have multiple `Buttons` from which you want to get their click events. If you define an anonymous inner class for each of them you are creating extra `Objects`. But as I said before, both patterns are functionally the same.